# Sold BC but funds not received into Bank

Tags: transactions, sell-bitcoins

I'm new to BC. I've bought using Blockchain.info, linked to a Coinify account which I've had verified with ID etc.

Buying is fine - got that sorted, but it seemed sensible to try selling a small amount in case I ever want to do this quickly, so I used Blockchain.info to set up a sell order for £10. I entered my Bank details (IBAN etc) as requested. In my wallet I can see the Coinify Sell order, and that the transaction has been 'confirmed'. I can view this on the Blockchain too. But no funds have reached my bank account. Blockchain.info refer me to Coinify, Coinify have asked if I received confirmation from them, which I did not, but now appear not to answer my emails.

It's entirely possible I messed up the transaction as I'm new to it, but I'd be interested to hear any comments about what I've described so far. It's only 10GBP, but the principle will be the same whether I sell this or a larger amount. Have I gone about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

this is Coinify representative writing. We are sorry to hear that you have experienced issues using our sell service and would like to ensure that everything is in order. Unfortunately, based on this post, we cannot identify your specific case. Could you please submit a ticket to support@coinify.com with identifying info from the email address associated with your account? If you have submitted a ticket already, please refer to the ticket id in your email. At the moment we are experiencing longer response times (https://support.coinify.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/197/0/why-are-bitcoin-transactions-taking-longer-than-usual) but we want to assure you that every order and support request will be taken care of. Thank you for your understanding.

Best regards, Coinify team